# React Native: Value for uri can not be cast to string after refactoring

Tags: react-native

I am refactoring RN 0.62.2 project by putting the following section of view into a component. Here is the code before refactoring:

```
       <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{setModalDialog(index)}} >
            <FastImage 
                source={{uri:img_source}} 
                resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.cover} 
                key={index}
                style={{
                    width:width, 
                    height:ht, 
                    verticalAlign:0,
                    paddingTop:0,
                }}
            />
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

The code above is put into a component `GridImage` as follows:

```
   const GridImage = (img_source, width, ht, index) => {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{setModalDialog(index)}} >
                <FastImage 
                    source={{uri:img_source}} 
                    resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.cover} 
                    key={index}
                    style={{
                        width:width, 
                        height:ht, 
                        verticalAlign:0,
                        paddingTop:0,
                    }}
                />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    };
```

The `GridImage` is called as below in place of the block of `<TouchableOpacity>`

```
                    <GridImage
                        img_source={img_source}
                        width={width}
                        ht={ht}
                        index={index}
                       />
```

There is an error when the refactoring is executed:

[image]

What is the error about? The code before refactoring ran fine.

Answer (score 0):

The variable passed into component shall be wrapped in object. The following change in component declaration works:

const GridImage = ({img_source, width, ht, index}) => {...}